# Mmenu.js integration with Angular 7 Project

Tags: mmenu

I want to integrate Mmenu.js with the Angular 7 project. Could someone please help me out, when I am trying to initialize the Menu with nav id, I am getting the following error "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined" hence unable to see navigation however working fine with simple HTML js project

Comment: I've a  same problem. Have you found any solution for this?